# How to create a grid in matplotlib out of a 2D numpy array where the items are classes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, grid

I'm working with a 2D NumPy array of n dimensions where the items are a class Square that has a state of either a 1 or a 0. I didn't want to create a new array that contains the int values of my classes so is there a way I can map my array to a colored grid?

```
import numpy as np
from random import randrange

class Square():
    def __init__(self, state, pos):
        self.state = state
        self.pos = pos
        self.adj_sqs = []
        self.optimal_sq = []

        
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.state)

dim = 10
grid = np.array([[Square(randrange(2), [x,y]) for y in range (dim)] for x in range(dim)])
```

Comment: Wraapping that list of lists of `Squares` in an `array` does not gain you anything.  The list does not have a `state` attribute, and neither does the array.

Comment: I wrapped it into an array because I used Numpy methods and functions later in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a numeric array directly via `np.array([[Square(...).state for y in ...] for x in ...])`.  Or transform each element of the array of Square`s` to get their `state`:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np
from random import randrange

class Square():
    def __init__(self, state, pos):
        self.state = state
        self.pos = pos
        self.adj_sqs = []
        self.optimal_sq = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.state)

dim = 10
grid = np.array([[Square(randrange(2), [x, y]) for y in range(dim)] for x in range(dim)])
grid_np = np.array([[grid[x, y].state for y in range(dim)] for x in range(dim)])

plt.pcolor(np.arange(-0.5, dim), np.arange(-0.5, dim), grid_np, cmap=ListedColormap(['crimson', 'turquoise']))
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')  # show square as square
plt.xticks(range(dim))
plt.yticks(range(dim))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]